# Cannot sign in with different account or "Use another account"

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to integrate Microsoft sso with a Xamarin.Forms app.

I'm using Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.7.1

I struggling to sign in with different accounts on the same device since it seems that the first account is always picked no matter what I do.

1. User A signs in
2. User A signs out
3. User B enters the app opens the webview with the Microsoft login page and prompts the "Use another account" button but even after typing his account, the webview redirects it to back to the mobile app as user A.

Here's the code that handles sign-in and sing-out:

```cs
private IPublicClientApplication _publicClientApplication;

public AuthService()
{
    _publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Constants.MicrosoftAuthConstants.ClientId.Value)
        .WithAdfsAuthority(Constants.MicrosoftAuthConstants.Authority.Value)
        .WithRedirectUri(Constants.MicrosoftAuthConstants.RedirectUri.Value)
        .Build();
}

public async Task<string> SignInAsync()
{
    var authScopes = Constants.MicrosoftAuthConstants.Scopes.Value;
    AuthenticationResult authResult;

    try
    {
        // call to _publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent
        authResult = await GetAuthResultSilentlyAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
    {
        authResult = await _publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(authScopes)
                  .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.ParentWindow)
                  .ExecuteAsync();
    }

    return authResult.AccessToken;
}

private async Task<IAccount> GetCachedAccountAsync() => (await _publicClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

public async Task SignOutAsync()
{
    var firstCachedAccount = await GetCachedAccountAsync();
    await _publicClientApplication.RemoveAsync(firstCachedAccount);
}
```

A workaround is to use `Prompt.ForceLogin` but what's the point of sso if you have to type the credentials every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code `await _publicClientApplication.RemoveAsync(firstCachedAccount);` can jsut remove the user from the cache, it doesn't implement a signout method. So you need to do logout manually by the [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#send-a-sign-out-request) below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https://localhost/myapp/
```

Comment: I ended up using this right after I asked the question. But it's kinda odd to me that there isn't a "true" sign out method. As far I've seen in their issues of the main repo, they're working on an improvement. I suggest everybody that's having similar problems to keep an eye on their repo on Github.